# Partial fit multivariate SGDRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am currently trying to use the SGDRegressor from scikits learn to solve a multivariate target problem over a large dataset, X ~= (10^6,10^4). As such I am generating the design matrix (X) in parts with the following code, where each iteration produces a batch of size roughly (10^3,10^4):

```
design = self.__iterX__(events)
reglins = [linear_model.SGDRegressor(fit_intercept=True) for i in range(nTargets)]

for X,times in design:
    for i in range(nTargets):
        reglins[i].partial_fit(X,y.ix[times].values[:,i])
```

However I get the following stack trace:

```
File ".../Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 841, in partial_fit
    coef_init=None, intercept_init=None)
File ".../Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 812, in _partial_fit
    sample_weight, n_iter)
File ".../Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py", line 948, in _fit_regressor
    intercept_decay)
File "sgd_fast.pyx", line 508, in sklearn.linear_model.sgd_fast.plain_sgd (sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.c:8651)
    ValueError: floating-point under-/overflow occurred.
```

Looking around it seems that this can be cause by not normalizing X properly. I understand scikits learn has a variety of functions for this, however given that I generate X in blocks, is it enough to simply normalize each block or would I need to figure out a way to normalize whole columns at a time?

Incidentally, is there a particular reason that the partial_fit function does not allow multivariate targets?

Comment: "is it enough to simply normalize each block" -- depends. `StandardScaler` needs to be fit to data, then applied to other data. `Normalizer` is stateless so it can be applied without fitting, but it's more appropriate to frequency data than Gaussian features.

Answer (score 3):

You can fit one block and apply to others:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x1 = scalar.fit_transform(X_block_1)
xn = scalar.transform(X_block_n)
```

You can choose other normalization methods [from this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply ChuNan. Unfortunately I think this would only work if the statistics of the first block (or any single block) were representative of the whole data. This is not the case in my instance. For now I just run through the entire X generation to calculate mean and std then zscore on my way round the second time. Not the nicest solution.